# Angular module bind priority

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

If I have an Angular module X that has a dependency on module Y, and both X and Y have a directive that binds to the same event (e.g. "drop"), then will the bind function in my module X directive always get called first?  I ran some tests and it appears that way, but I'm not sure if that is just a coincidence.

Comment: You must settup directive priority: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must settup directive priority:

```
myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
   priority: 0, //setup the priotity here

   //directive definition
}
```

Take a deep look at: [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)